# How can I change the retention period used by SQL Server change tracking?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I have change tracking enabled on a SQL Server database. I originally configured the database to use auto cleanup with a retention period of 3 days. Now that everything is running I would like to update that retention window to 10 days. How can I do that using a SQL statement? I don't want to turn off change tracking and reconfigure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation on this isn't very clear and the syntax is a little unusual. The easiest way to do this outside of SSMS is to issue this statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET CHANGE_TRACKING (CHANGE_RETENTION = 10 DAYS)
```